# Grid finder python: 3 parameters

Tags: python

I am trying to code a grid finder that will find the optimal values for my 3 parameters a, b and c based on two lists, `x3data` and `y3data`. My function is defined at the top.

```
delx=np.zeros(1)
dely=np.zeros(1)  
    
def func(x, a, b, c):
   #y = 100*a*x + 100*b
   
   #y = y - 360.*np.floor(y/360.)    # subtracting 360 times the nearest integer of y/360 from y
   
   delx = np.cos(a*x + b) - c 
   dely = np.sin(a*x + b) 
   rad = np.sqrt(delx*delx+dely*dely)
   y=np.arccos(delx/rad)
   ysign1 = np.sign(dely)
   ysign2 = (1. - ysign1)/2.
   y = ysign2 * 2. * np.pi + (ysign1 *y)
   y = y*180./np.pi      # in degrees 
   return y


ndat=len(x3data)
ngrid=50

chimin=1.e10
    
apar_best = 0.0
bpar_best = 0.0
cpar_best = 0.0

for i in range(ngrid):
    for j in range(ngrid):
        for k in range(ngrid):
            apar=10.*i/float(ngrid-1)
            bpar=1.*j/float(ngrid-1)
            cpar=1.*k/float(ngrid-1)
            chi=0.
            for l in range(ndat):
                diff=(y3data[l]-func(x3data[l],apar,bpar, cpar))*np.pi/180.
                chi=chi+(np.sin(diff))**2
                if(chi<chimin):
                    print(i, j, k, apar, bpar, cpar, np.sqrt(chi/float(ndat)))
                    chimin=chi
                    apar_best=apar
                    bpar_best=bpar
                    cpar_best = cpar
    
print("best fit results:")                                          

print(apar_best, bpar_best, cpar_best, np.sqrt(chimin/float(ndat)))           
print("a =" , apar_best)
print("b =" , bpar_best)
print("c =" , cpar_best)



best fit results:
0.0 0.8367346938775511 0.673469387755102 6.264895969973369e-05
a = 0.0
b = 0.8367346938775511
c = 0.673469387755102
```

I keep getting the same values for a, b and c which are incorrect. They are shown above. Not sure where I am going wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a short explanation of my grid finder line by line:

1. First, the code declares the length of the x3data array as the variable ndat, and the grid size as ngrid.
2. It then sets the chimin (minimum chi) value to a very large number.
3. It also declares three variables apar_best, bpar_best and cpar_best and sets them to 0.0.
4. The code then begins a for loop that runs the i variable from 0 to ngrid-1.
5. Inside the first for loop, there is another for loop that runs the j variable from 0 to ngrid-1.
6. Inside the second for loop, there is a third for loop that runs the k variable from 0 to ngrid-1.
7. For each set of i, j, and k values, the code declares three variables apar, bpar and cpar, and sets them to 10*i/ngrid-1, j/ngrid-1 and k/ngrid-1 respectively.
8. Next, it sets the chi value to 0.
9. After that, the code begins another for loop that runs the l variable from 0 to ndat.
10. Inside this loop, the code calculates the difference between the y3data and the func and stores it in the diff variable.
11. The code then calculates the chi value by squaring the sin of the diff, and adds it to the existing chi value.
12. If the chi value is less than the chimin value, it prints the values of i, j, k, apar, bpar, cpar and the square root of the chi value divided by ndat.
13. Finally, the code sets the chimin value to the current chi value, and the apar_best, bpar_best and cpar_best values to the current apar, bpar and cpar values.

Comment: Could you add some info about your definition of **grid finder**? Sorry but your algorithm is mysterious for my knowledge..

Comment: I have added an explanation for the grid finder and also what my function looks like

Comment: can you add the x3data and y3data as well as the expected output?

Comment: The x3data and y3data are lists of time and angular measurements respectively and each contain 214 elements. The expected output would be something like: """a=0.4, b=6.0 and c=0.77"""